# map in clojure giving unexpected result

Tags: dictionary, clojure

Using map in clojure, checking whether a string contains uppercase character.

```
(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case %) %) "Hello")
```

The expected result.

```
(true false false false false)
```

unfortunately, the result is unexpected.

```
(false false false false false)
```

I did an experiment when I replace "H" in the first "%", the result is still unexpected.

```
(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case "H") %) "Hello") 

(false false false false false)
```

When I replace "H" in the second "%", the result is changed, it is an expected result.

```
(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case %) "H) "Hello") 

(true false false false false)
```

What's wrong with that? Please feel free to comment.

Comment: You said you need to check whether a string contains an uppercased character so am I right in assuming you don't need to know which one? In this case why not checking  the string as whole? `(= (str/lower-case "Hello") "Hello")` should tell you whether your string was lowercased initially

Comment: It is a small part of program, for some reasons, I need to check a long string with one character by character.

Comment: You compare string with a char, your test actually looks like this: `(= "H" \H)` which is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you assume wrongly that `map` dissects the string `"Hello"` into `("H" "e" "l" "l" "o")` but this it not the case!

Try:

```
(map identity "Hello") ;; => (\H \e \l \l \o)
```

So map dissects a string into a list of characters and not a list of single character strings.

So your `(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case %) %) "Hello")` is comparing
`(clojure.string/upper-case \H)` which results in `"H"` with `\H`.
Since the one is a single character string, the other however is a character, the result is `false` - because of type difference.

```
(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case %) (str %)) "Hello")
```

However does what you expected from the original code.
It returns:

```
(true false false false false)
```

#### Function

The most efficient way might be to use regex:

```
(defn has-upper-case? [s] (boolean (re-find #"[A-Z]" s)))
```

Less strictly (no boolean returning, but either the first upper single character string of the string from left to right or `nil` if not found any):

```
(defn has-upper-case? [s] (re-find #"[A-Z]" s))
```

Comment: Instead of (if condition true false) you could just use the condition directly as a truthy/falsey value or, if you really want a Boolean result, wrap it like this: (boolean condition) -- that will return strictly true or false.

Comment: @SeanCorfield, Where could I find an example of your suggestion?

Comment: fellow your comment, instead of "if" statement,  I use a character or nil value directly. (map #(re-find #"[A-Z]" (str %)) "Hello"), thank for your help,

Comment: @madeinQuant True, I just wanted to follow the convention that a `?` function must actually return a boolean - isn't it? - `(if (re-find #"[A-Z]" "Hello") true false)` would really return `true` or `false` while without the `if` clouses, it returns `"H"` (so some string) or `nil`.

Comment: @madeinQuant The point of using Regex is that it makes `map` superfluous. `re-find` stops scanning as soon as it sees the first upper character in the string. No further character then is examined -> thus contributing to performance. So when using regex, you can input the entire string at once - and the scanning will end as soon as it finds first match.

Comment: @SeanCorfield Thank you for the hint. I didn't know about `boolean` - coming from Common Lisp.

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, comparing a character to a string will not work. Comparing strings will work:

```clj
(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case %) (str %)) "Hello")
=> (true false false false false)
```

However this is more direct:

```clj
(map #(Character/isUpperCase %) "Hello")
=> (true false false false false)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, combined your comment with regular expressions. I found a answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can't compare String with a char. Sequence made out of string is a list of chars.

```
(seq "Hello")
;; => (\H \e \l \l \o)
(map class "Hello")
;; => (java.lang.Character java.lang.Character java.lang.Character java.lang.Character java.lang.Character)
```

So in your case your test boils down to

```
(= "H" \H) ;; => false
```

which is false.

To make it work, try one of the following:

```
;; compare strings
(map #(= (clojure.string/upper-case %) (str %)) "Hello")
;; => (true false false false false)

;; compare chars
(map #(= (first (clojure.string/upper-case %)) %) "Hello")
;; => (true false false false false)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, your answer help me to clarify some concepts of data structures in Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

`upper-case` converts string to all upper-case.

ref: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/upper-case

You need to use something like that:

```
 (some #(Character/isUpperCase %) "Hello") => true
 (some #(Character/isUpperCase %) "hello") => nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You're being caught by undocumented behaviour of `clojure.string/upper-case`:

- It works on any object, not just on strings.
- It always returns a string.

So, for example,

```
(clojure.string/upper-case +)
=> "CLOJURE.CORE$_PLUS_@19CFE007"
```

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/32b2759a4d3508926ca2ec0f91413e6892b44d47/src/clj/clojure/string.clj#L207), you see that it applies `.toString` before `.toUpperCase`.

So it works on single characters too. But it returns a string, not - what I expected - a character:

```
(clojure.string/upper-case 1)
=> "1"
```

The remedy is to apply `upper-case` to the string as a whole, then use `map` with `=` to compare the original string to the converted one, character by character:

```
(#(map = (clojure.string/upper-case %) %) "Hello")
=> (true false false false false)
```

Or, using `(fn [...] ...)` instead of `#(...)`,

```
((fn [coll] (map = (clojure.string/upper-case coll) coll)) "Hello")
=> (true false false false false)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. May I ask a question? Why apply a set "#" operator in front of map and making a comparison "=" after map?

Comment: @madeinQuant `#( ... )` is an [anonymous function literal](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#_anonymous_function) - a shorthand used for writing tiny functions. You used it yourself in the first line of code in the question. I'll change the answer to use `fn` instead.

Comment: @madeinQuant The `=` after the `map` compares the original string to the converted one, character by character. The `=` is followed by two collections, hence is invoked as a function of two arguments. For example, `(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])` yields `(5 7 9)`.